# Probability: IID random process notation question.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am giving $p_X(x) = \exp(-x)u(x)$. What is $u(x)$? I ask because when I evaluate the probability greater than one, I have 
$$
\int_1^{\infty}e^{-x}u(x)dx
$$
which I know is equal to $e^{-1}$ so why does $u(x)\Bigl|_1^{\infty} \Rightarrow u(1) = 1$ and what is $u(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ would appear to be the Unit Step Function.    It is a piecewise function defined as $1$ everywhere the argument is at least zero, and $0$ where the argument is less than zero.

$$u(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & : x\geq 0 \\ 0 & : x < 0\end{cases}$$

It indicates that the support of the probability density function $p_X(x)$ is $x\in[0, \infty)$

Comment: Is it common for authors to just write it in without stating what it is? What I mean is it just assumed that it should be my natural conclusion when I see an unknown $u(x)$?

Comment: @Dustin  Well, they *should* not assume it, but it does often seem the case.  The definition might be buried somewhere at the beginning of the text, or in the glossary.

Comment: Ok thanks. In many of books, I know when I am dealing with the unit step since it is written as $\mathcal{U}$ not just $u$.

Comment: @dustin Yes. That is the more common convention.  But sometimes you have to watch out for the unconventional.